# How to pass custom date range to clarity.ms?

Tags: pyspark, ms-clarity

I need to pull data from clarity.ms using pyspark. When I referred documentation it is has option like numOfDays Instead do we have any option to filter on custom date range like startDate and EndDate

```
reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/clarity/setup-and-installation/clarity-data-export-api
```

I have alos tried below but no luck

```
api_url = "https://www.clarity.ms/export-data/api/v1/project-live-insights"

# Construct the API request URL with start date and end date
request_url = f"{api_url}?startDate={start_date}&endDate={end_date}"
```